# Is there magic in the regular expression of detectmobilebrowser.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, mobile, user-agent

I've read the code of [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

I'm puzzled about it and hope somebody can explain how it works:

(Sorry, I found only a minimized version and I've added some linefeeds for better readability, hopefully without breaking the code.)

```
(function (a,b) {
     if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry
        |blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge
        |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?
        |phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.browser|link)
        |vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)| 

        ... and many more patterns ...

        |zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))
    window.location=b
})(
    navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, // argument a
    'http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile'                  // argument b
);
```

My question is:

The regular expression is tested against the first 4 characters of `navigator.userAgent` or `navigator.vendor` or `window.opera` (the first truthy value).

What confuses me:

- Many of the components of the regular expression are much longer than 4 characters.
- Most userAgents I've seen are like `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; ...` so the first 4 characters will be 'Mozi' in many cases.

How can it work?

My simple test in Chrome Console:

```
/android|blackberry/i.test('Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; ...'.substr(0,4))
// -> false
/android|blackberry/i.test('Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; ...')
// -> true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve been misled by the minified code. It actually goes like this:

```
if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).../i.test(a) ||
    /1207|6310|6590|3gso.../i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {
    window.location = b
}
```